# New variable ajaxObj does not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

For some weird reason this line of code is not working:

```
var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/status_system.php");
```

What could it be?
I figured it must be the above line using window.alert's since after that line window.alert does not run.

Full code:

The function is called:

```
$status_ui = '<textarea id="statustext" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)" placeholder="What&#39;s new with you '.$u.'?"></textarea>';
$status_ui .= '<button id="statusBtn" onclick="postToStatus(\'status_post\',\'a\',\''.$u.'\',\'statustext\')">Post</button>';
```

The function:

```
function postToStatus(action,type,user,ta){
    window.alert("status passed 1");
    var data = _(ta).value;
    if(data == ""){
        alert("Type something first weenis");
        return false;
    }
    window.alert("status passed 2");
    _("statusBtn").disabled = true;
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "php_parsers/newsfeed_system.php");
    window.alert("status passed 3");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            var datArray = ajax.responseText.split("|");
            if(datArray[0] == "post_ok"){
                var sid = datArray[1];
                data = data.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace(/\n/g,"<br />").replace(/\r/g,"<br />");
                var currentHTML = _("statusarea").innerHTML;
                _("statusarea").innerHTML = '<div id="status_'+sid+'" class="status_boxes"><div><b>Posted by you just now:</b> <span id="sdb_'+sid+'"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deleteStatus(\''+sid+'\',\'status_'+sid+'\');" title="DELETE THIS STATUS AND ITS REPLIES">delete status</a></span><br />'+data+'</div></div><textarea id="replytext_'+sid+'" class="replytext" onkeyup="statusMax(this,250)" placeholder="write a comment here"></textarea><button id="replyBtn_'+sid+'" onclick="replyToStatus('+sid+',\'<?php echo $u; ?>\',\'replytext_'+sid+'\',this)">Reply</button>'+currentHTML;
                _("statusBtn").disabled = false;
                _(ta).value = "";
            } else {
                alert(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("action="+action+"&type="+type+"&user="+user+"&data="+data);
    window.alert("status passed 4");
}
```

newsfeed_system.php

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "status_post"){
    // Make sure post data is not empty
    if(strlen($_POST['data']) < 1){
        mysqli_close($db_conx);
        echo "data_empty";
        exit();
    }
    // Make sure type is a
    if($_POST['type'] != "a"){
        mysqli_close($db_conx);
        echo "type_unknown";
        exit();
    }
    // Clean all of the $_POST vars that will interact with the database
    $type = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['type']);
    $data = htmlentities($_POST['data']);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $data);

    // Insert the status post into the database now
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsfeed(author, type, data, postdate) 
            VALUES('$log_username','$type','$data',now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
    mysqli_query($db_conx, "UPDATE newsfeed SET osid='$id' WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    echo "post_ok|$id";
    exit();
}
```

Ajax methods:

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: what is `ajaxObj`? Is it part of a js library? If so you should list it so that we know what you are working with.

Comment: @PatrickEvans edited the post to show the ajax methods...

Comment: check your javascript console for errors

Comment: @PatrickEvans thank you! I did not know that existed on a live web site (I'm still learning :P) and i figure out i did not reference the ajax code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax is not refrenced! You need to include the library or put the code for calling an 'ajaxObj'.